# What does SUM(a;b;c...) semicolon stand for in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

For example, SUM(A1:T1; W1:Z1) in Excel function , what's the difference between this,SUM(A1:T1, W1:Z1). ',' and ';' could be exchangeable in this sum function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of a comma or semi-colon in this context depends on your regional settings. In countries where a comma is used as the decimal point, a semi-colon replaces the function of a comma-as-parameter-separator. They mean the same thing. But you will probably find that your SUM formula will only work with one or other, depending on the Windows regional settings.

Comment: Acutally I have found that in Windows Excel,it uses comma,in Mac Excel it uses semicolon;