# How to prevent automatic extra space in VBA editor when inserting formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert formula equation to worksheet with VBA code.

In a worksheet, this code works.

`=COUNTIF(L2:L101; ">"&A1)`

In VBA code, I've tried following code, which returning "FALSE".

```
 Cells(3, 20).Formula = "=COUNTIF(L2:L101; ">"&A1)"
```

The problem here is that, when I enter above code line into VBA editor, it automatically adds extra space before and after '>'.

So the code will be like;

```
 Cells(3, 20).Formula = "=COUNTIF(L2:L101; " > "&A1)"
```

How can I eliminate spaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Vba: Double quotes in formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677210/excel-vba-double-quotes-in-formula) and [How do I put double quotes in a string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024724/how-do-i-put-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-vba). `"` should be `""` inside of strings

Comment: Aside from the double quotes you are also using a semicolon, which should be a comma in vba. So try `Cells(3, 20).Formula = "=COUNTIF(L2:L101,"">""&A1)"`

Comment: Using `;` instead of `,` to separate arguments can be needed if your regional settings use `,` as the decimal separator instead of `.` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396154/2127508)

Comment: @barrowc, that's not how VBA works unfortunately. When writing VBA you will always need to use the US-English conventions for the list separator, which is the comma. This will be translated in your sheet with the semicolon.

Comment: @jvdv the [FormulaLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal) and [FormulaR1C1Local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1local) properties use formulas in accordance with the user's regional settings - including using `;` as a list separator if appropriate. The non-localised Formula properties always use US English separators though so I was incorrect to say that using the localised separators was ever needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
 Cells(3, 20).formula = "=COUNTIF(L2:L101, "">"" &A1)"
```

You are using Semicolon instead of `,` & you should use double Quotes inside the Formula for using Quotes

Comment: The code works like magic! Thank you very much!